# ServiceStack OrmlLite Get Scalar output from Stored Procedure

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

How can I get the scalar output from Stored Procedure? When I execute the below statement, it returns DBNull.

We are using ServiceStack.OrmLite 4.5.8

```
var le = db.<<SP Name>>(param1, param2)
                .TryGetParameterValue("output_id", out object val);
```

OrmLite T4 template generated the following code:

```
public static OrmLiteSPStatement SPName(this IDbConnection db, string @Param1 = null, string @Param2 = null, @Output_id = null)
{
    var dbCmd = (DbCommand)OrmLiteConfig.ExecFilter.CreateCommand(db).ToDbCommand();
    dbCmd.CommandText = "SP NAME";
    dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dbCmd.Parameters.Add(CreateNewParameter(dbCmd,"Param1",@param1,ParameterDirection.Input,DbType.AnsiString));
    dbCmd.Parameters.Add(CreateNewParameter(dbCmd,"Param2",@param2,ParameterDirection.Input,DbType.AnsiString));        
    dbCmd.Parameters.Add(CreateNewParameter(dbCmd,"Output_id",@output_id,ParameterDirection.InputOutput,DbType.Int32));
    dbCmd.Parameters.Add(CreateNewParameter(dbCmd,"__ReturnValue",0,ParameterDirection.ReturnValue,DbType.Int32));
    return new OrmLiteSPStatement(db, dbCmd);
}
```

Thanks
rudrvij

Comment: var count = db.Scalar<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable");

Comment: In my case, we are running a stored proc that computes a value and returns it in output param.

Comment: Does it work with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = db.Scalar<int>("EXEC [SP Name] @param1, @param2", new { param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2" });
```